# Are structs that contain packed structs packed themselves?

Tags: c++, struct, packing

Suppose I have a struct which contains other structs, which are not packed:

```
struct ContainerOfNonPacked
{
    NonPacked1 first;
    NonPacked2 second;
};
```

And then I have a struct which contains other structs which are packed:

```
struct ContainerOfPacked
{
    Packed1 first; // declaration of struct had __attribute__((packed))
    Packed2 second; // ditto
};
```

The first is not going to be packed by the compiler (i.e. there's no guarantee that there will be no "holes" inside the struct). It might coincidentally have no holes, but that's not what the question is about.

What about the second container, that contains packed structs? Is there any *guarantee* that a struct consisting solely of packed structs as its fields is itself packed?

Comment: It depends on the implementation - there is no "standard C++" answer.   If `first` and `second` have different alignment requirements, then the containing struct will probably have padding between the two members, even if they are both packed.

Comment: What I mean is that the first case has "no guarantees of packedness". I understand that in general, it's always possible to coincidentally have a packed struct, but that's not what I'm looking for. The second case actually appears to be guaranteed to be packed (see answer below): but I'm not super-clear, and I would love a more authoritative answer if you've got one.

Comment: If you know this to be implementation-defined, would you mind writing an answer? That's very helpful information, especially since the only answer here uses just an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: it is up to the compiler and is not a behaviour one can depend on.

For the case of GCC and clang, structs that contain only packed structs are themselves "packed". They will not have any padding "holes" in them.

Here is an example to illustrate (godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/2noSpP):

We have four structs, Packed1, Packed2, NonPacked1, and NonPacked2.

```
#include <cstdint>

struct Packed1
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint64_t b;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct NonPacked1
{
    uint16_t a;
    // Padding of 2 bytes
    uint32_t b;
    uint8_t c;
};

// We have two structs of the same size, one packed and one not
static_assert(sizeof(NonPacked1) == 12);
static_assert(sizeof(Packed1) == 12);

struct Packed2
{
    uint64_t a;
    uint64_t b;
} __attribute__((packed)); // packing has no effect, but better for illustration

struct NonPacked2
{
    uint32_t a;
    // Padding of 4 bytes
    uint64_t b;
};

// And again, two structs of the same size
static_assert(sizeof(Packed2) == 16);
static_assert(sizeof(NonPacked2) == 16);
```

Packed1 and Packed2 go into a ContainerOfPacked struct, and the other two into a ContainerOfNonPacked.

```
struct ContainerOfNonPacked
{
    NonPacked1 first; // 12 bytes
    // Padding of 4 bytes between the non-packed struct-fields
    NonPacked2 second; // 16 bytes
};

struct ContainerOfPacked
{
    Packed1 first; // 12
    // No padding between the packed struct-fields
    Packed2 second; // 16
};

static_assert(sizeof(ContainerOfNonPacked) == 32);
static_assert(sizeof(ContainerOfPacked) == 28);
```

As the code comments and static asserts show, the container of packed structs does not have padding holes inside it. It behaves as if it is itself "packed".

Although this is an answer, I'm also looking for answers which can cite the relevant parts of the Standard or some other authoritative/theoretical explanations.

Comment: What about a struct containing both Packed and NonPacked?  If you intend to only ask about a struct whose only members are Packed, then you should say so clearly in the question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the question to specify that the container contains solely member structs which are all packed. But more generally, I would love to get an answer that could define the rules surrounding packing and how it "extends" to enclosing classes, if such rules exist.

Comment: It's all up to the compiler , there are no independent rules

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. Then I won't depend on this coincidental behaviour.